# Проверка логера на root в log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

```
Logger logger=LogManager.getLogger(Test.class);
```

Помогите реализовать проверку, получил ли я логгер с настройками Root, или нет

Comment: Тут не нужна проверка. Это не рут логгер.

Comment: @talex если для этого класса нету логгера в конфигурации, то он вернет root логгер, так что не факт что это не root логгер

Comment: Оно вернет логгер с настройками идентичными рутовому, но с другим префиксом.

Comment: @talex Спасибо за объяснение, поправил вопрос

Comment: Какие именно настройки вас интересуют? LogLevel? Appenders? какие-то другие? Мне кажется если вы объясните зачем вам это, то будет проще ответить на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @talex Нужно проверить, был ли реализована конфигурация в log4j2.xml для класса (любая, кроме Root) если нет, то настроить конфиг программно. Интересует, взял ли Logger настройки от Root, или любого другого логгера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел следующий способ:

```
var root = LoggerContext.getContext().getConfiguration().getLoggerConfig(LoggerConfig.ROOT);
var log = LoggerContext.getContext().getConfiguration().getLoggerConfig(Test.class.getName());
root.equals(log);
```

И ещё один:

```
LoggerContext.getContext().getConfiguration().getLoggers().containsKey(Test.class.getName())
```